Implementing regularization in a least squares problem for B-splines
For fitting a B-spline curve to a set of data points, most code utilise the following function : torch.linalg.lstsq to solve the least squares minimization problem.
I am wondering wether I could introduce a separate regularization term in this least squares expression itself but there is no implementation for this in the pytorch repo.
Moreover, the function is implemented in C and not python so customizing it poses a significant task.
I tried adding the regularization term to the loss function but I would like a more local control over the spline function.
